# View PHAsset in collection view cell

Tags: swift

I have an image picker controller that I could choose multiple pictures with and then sets an array of PHAssets, using it's delegate method I passed the array to another view controller which should convert the PHAssets to [UIImage], I want the UIImage array to be the datasource for an imageView in a collection view.

```
    var assets = [PHAsset]()
    var uiimage = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.register(postPicturesCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }



    func phassetToUIImage(){

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.exact
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.highQualityFormat

    for asset in assets {
        if asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.image {

            PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset , targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.default, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (pickedImage, info) in
                self.uiimage.append(pickedImage!)
                debugPrint(self.uiimage)
            })
        }
    }
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

The print statment prints this to the console

```
[<UIImage: 0x1d40bf680>, {3024, 4032}]
```

which means that the array is not empty.

Here is how I'm passing the data between view controllers

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: ImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImageAssets assets: [PHAsset]) {

    debugPrint(assets)

    let vc = postViewController()
    vc.assets = assets
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The print statement prints

```
[<PHAsset: 0x105fd5500> E23A656E-D3D8-4193-9864-BEBF2323E640/L0/001 mediaType=1/0, sourceType=1, (3024x4032), creationDate=2018-07-22 13:50:36 +0000, location=0, hidden=0, favorite=0 ]
```

My cell class

```
class postPicturesCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var imgView: UIImageView = {
    var img = UIImageView()
    img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    return img
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    imgView = UIImageView()
    setUpViews()
}

func setUpViews(){
    imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(imgView)
    imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

cellForItemAt

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! postPicturesCell
    cell.imgView.image = uiimage[indexPath.row]
    collectionView.reloadData()
    return cell
}
```

The image does not show on the collection view, can anyone points out to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload inside as `PHImageManager.default().requestImage` is asynchronous

```
debugPrint(self.uiimage)
self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```

//

Or use `DispatchGroup`

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

for asset in assets {
    if asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.image {
        group.enter()
        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset , targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.default, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (pickedImage, info) in
            self.uiimage.append(pickedImage!)
            debugPrint(self.uiimage)
            group.leave()
        })
    }
}


group.notify(queue: .main) {

  self.collectionView.reloadData()

}
```

//

```
picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the app crashes now. I tried both solutions.

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16ae6ff30)  Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000016ae6ff30

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm calling `phassetToUIImage()` in viewDidLoad

Comment: I think **postViewController** is not even shown ?? try to make it inside completion of picker dismiss

Comment: It does show, but the pictures don't show. I tried it and I got the same error. Would it be possible to pass an array of UIImages? I have tried to, but I get an empty array.

Comment: The solution worked after deleting  `collectionView.reloadData()` in `cellForItemAt`

Comment: yes , reload can't be there as it'll cause recursion

Comment: It gives this erro and terminate the app 
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue ?